# Grep all instances of strings that start with certain characters

Tags: linux, bash, grep, cat

I would like to grep out all instances of strings that start with the characters 'rs' (from just one file) and pipe the full string into a new file.
I managed to get the count of the instances but I don't know how to get them into the new file:

```
grep -c rs < /home/Stephanie/this.txt
698572
```

An example of a line in the file is:

```
1203823    forward   efjdhgv   rs124054t8 dhdfhfhs
12045345    back   efjdkkjf   rs12445368 dhdfhfhs
```

I just want to grab the rs string and move it to a ne file.
Can someone help me out with the piping? I read around a bit but what I found wasn't particularly helpful to me.
thanks

Comment: try this: `grep -c '^rs' this.txt > out.txt`

Comment: @kev Could you explain the ^ and why you put it in ''?

Comment: @kev and that just gave me file with 0 in it. It didn't find any matches though I know they are there

Comment: @Stephopolis, do you mean `strings` or `lines`?

Comment: I just want the string that starts with rs. I will update the questions

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd suggest something like this:

```
egrep -o "(\s(rs\S+))" data.txt | cut -d " " -f 2 > newfile.txt
```

`\s` looks for something that starts with any whitespace character

`(rs\S+)` and then searches for a string that starts with "rs" and is followed by any non-whitespace character

The results still have the white spaces in it, which we don't want, so we "cut" them out, before the content gets written to new file.

Comment: Thank you so much for the working solution and the explanation of it's different aspects.

Answer (score 1):

Using Perl:

```
 perl -lane 'print $1 while (/\b(rs\w+)/g)' input
```

Or using `tr` and `grep`:

```
tr '[ \t]' '[\n\n]' < input | grep '^rs'
```

here `^` matches start of a line.

Comment: Great usage of tr and grep!

Answer (score 1):

Super old, but wanted to add to this. @kev grep -c '^rs' would dump out a count of all the lines that start with rs which none do.

To do this relatively easily with most standard binaries, you could use:

```
cat text.file | awk {'print $4'} | grep '^rs'
```

This would cat the file, pull out the fourth field of each line and only pull lines that start with rs

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -F -lane '$a=$_;for(@F){if(/^rs/){print $a;last}}' your_file
```

or

```
perl -lne 'print if(/[\s]rs/ || /^rs/)' your_file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Grep Command:

```
grep -w -o "rs[0-9a-z]*"
```